# rCharts dTable Error

Tags: r, rcharts, devtools

Hi I'm new to rCharts and could definitely use some help.  I'm getting the error below when I try to run the following.

Code:

```
dTable(airquality, sPaginationType = "full_numbers")
```

Error:

```
Error in as.character(tools:::httpdPort) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
```

Also when I try ?dTable I get the message:

```
No documentation for ‘dTable’ in specified packages and libraries:
you could try ‘??dTable’
```

I installed rCharts and devtools using:

```
install.packages("devtools")
```

and

```
install.packages("base64enc")
devtools::install_github("ramnathv/rCharts")
```

then I called both libraries using library(devtools) and library(rCharts).

Any tips greatly appreciated.

Comment: dTable(...) does not exist in rCharts. But you got a great hint in the error it threw out.

Comment: @miles2know yes it does. We can check the namespace and see that it exists. rCharts::dTable .

OP is getting this error because there is no documentation associated with the dTable function

Comment: Also please provide a reproducible example of your error

Comment: This is from the Quiz in JHU's coursera class.

Answer (score 0):

I created a **fig** directory under my current working directory, ran the following code and it created an html file with the sortable table in the **fig** directory:

```
#install.packages("devtools")
install.packages("base64enc")
require(base64enc)
library(devtools)
require(rCharts)
data("airquality")
table1 <- dTable(airquality, sPaginationType = "full_numbers")
table1$save('./fig/table1.html', standalone=TRUE)
```